# TypeError: <Product: Tablet> is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, session, typeerror, cart

I am trying to implement a cart application (from django by example chapter 7) using django. However from my product list, when i click add to cart, I'm supposed to be taken to the cart detail (detail.html template) page instead i get the error `<Product: Tablet> is not JSON serializable`
I am using the following `cart.py` file. Suspect the error is coming from the `__iter__` method. Please help

cart.py

```
from django.conf import settings

from resource_manager.models import Product


class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        """
        Initialize the cart.
        """
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            # save an empty cart in the session
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        """
        Add a product to the cart or update its quantity.
        :param product:
        :param quantity:
        :param update_quantity:
        :return:
        """

        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0}
            # self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price': str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        # update the session cart
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        # mark the session as "modified" to make sure it is saved
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        """
        Remove a product from the cart.
        :param product:
        :return:
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
        self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Iterate over the items in the cart and get the products
        from the database.
        """
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        # get the product objects and add them to the cart
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        # self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product
        for item in self.cart.values():
            # item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            # item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Count all items in the cart.
        """
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    # def get_total_price(self):
    #     return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        # remove cart from session
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.session.modified = True
```

here is the `Product` model

```
class Product(models.Model):

    NAME_CHOICES = (
        ('Radio', 'Radio'),
        ('Tablet', 'Tablet'),
        ('Mat', 'Mat'),
        ('Workbook', 'Workbook'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=NAME_CHOICES, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='resource_manager/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    # available = models.BooleanField(editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def is_available(self):
        if self.stock_count > 0:
            available = True
        else:
            available = False
        return available

    @property
    def stock_count(self):
        count = Equipment.objects.filter(equipment_type=self.name).count()
        return count

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('resource_manager:product_detail',
                       args=[self.pk])
```

Comment: As indicated by the error, the issue is with your `Product` model which has some properties that cannot be automatically be converted to JSON. You need to look there to see what properties is has that cannot be serialized. There are several [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872604/json-dump-throwing-typeerror-is-not-json-serializable-on-seemingly-vali) [dealing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) with how to address that.

Comment: The Product model contains an image field but images are stored not as the images, but as urls to the location where they are stored.

Comment: You should pass your object in `json` mode, not objective. so you can create a serializer layer and call it on your objects