# How to save the contents of text files as a list in json format sequentially (not concatenation)

Tags: python, json, serialization, text-files

I have thousands of text files in a directory, and would like to save the content of each file in a list (one big file-list) while maintaining the order of the files as they are in the directory. The texts are not to be concatenated. Please see example of my desired output.

```
Example=['textual content of file one', 'textual content of file two', 'textual content of file three'.....textual content of file n]
```

My attempt:

```
filelist=[file-1,file-2,...file-n]
destinationfile="C:\\XXXXX\\dump_large_json.txt"
with open(destinationfile, 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for file in filelist:
        with open(file, 'r') as f2:
            h=json.dump(f2,f)
```

output:

> TypeError: Object of type 'TextIOWrapper' is not JSON serializable

Any ideas on how to serially dump text files in json format would be appreciated.

Comment: Follow a similar procedure outlined, you need to read from `f`.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872604/json-dump-throwing-typeerror-is-not-json-serializable-on-seemingly-vali

Comment: It is not a duplicate question, the texts are not to be concatenated as in the solutions you guys pointed out.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it is not a duplicate question, the solution you pointed me to involves concatenating the file contexts in one large file which is not what I want. The output file should be a list that contains the textual content of each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the text contents of each file to a `list`, and then dump the resulting object to a json file:

```
filelist = [file-1, file-2, ... file-n]
destinationfile = "C:\\XXXXX\\dump_large_json.txt"

contents = []
for file in filelist:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        contents.append(f.read())

with open(destinationfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(contents, f)
```