# How to implement RSA encryption/decryption on python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, rsa

I am implementing RSA encryption/decryption. The data which is to be encrypted contains different data types. Hence I have used dictionary in python. However I am getting errors. I am attaching code snippet. Please provide solution !! Thank you.

```
import base64
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
import hashlib
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from Crypto import Random


class SplitStore:
....

  def encrPayload(self, payload):

    modulus_length = 256 * 13  # use larger value in production
    privatekey = RSA.generate(modulus_length, Random.new().read)
    public_key = privatekey.publickey()

    private_pem = privatekey.exportKey().decode()
    with open('private_pem.pem', 'w') as pr:
    pr.write(private_pem)

    byte_payload = payload.encode('utf-8', 'strict')
    #print("Byte Payload:{} ".format(byte_payload))

    encrypted_payload = public_key.encrypt(byte_payload, 32)[0]
    #print("type:{}".format(type(encrypted_payload)))
    #print("\nEncrpted METADATA: {}".format(encrypted_payload))

    bchain_file = open("blockchain/file.dat", "wb")
    bchain_file.write((encrypted_payload))

  def createMetaData(self):
    time_stamp = os.stat("/home/pc-01/sample.pdf").st_ctime
    #print("\nTIMESTAMP: {}".format(time_stamp))

    hash_data = hashlib.sha512(self.pdfReader).hexdigest()
    #print("\nHASHDATA : {}".format(hash_data))

    secret_keys = self.j   #j is a list of keys
    #print("List of secret keys: {}".format(self.j))
    #print("String conv: " + str(secret_keys[0]))

    #Creating a dictionary
    payload = {
      "time_stamp" : time_stamp, #int
      "hash" : hash_data, #string
      "keys" : secret_keys #list
    }
    #print("\nPAYLOAD: " + payload)
    return payload 
    ...


def main():

  s1 = SplitStore()
  s1.initializeData()
  ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

`secret_keys` in `payload` is a list containing keys in bytes format. After running the code I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
....... chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode return _iterencode(o, 0) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable") 
TypeError: b'Vm3pb7XRJ4W_8M1ShKHAGiuDa2PT1DN_0ncjf0hmNJU=' is not JSON serializable
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what errors you are facing, and at which lines

Comment: secret_keys in payload is list containing keys in bytes format. after running the code i get following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  .......
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: b'Vm3pb7XRJ4W_8M1ShKHAGiuDa2PT1DN_0ncjf0hmNJU=' is not JSON serializable
it is saying bytes are not JSON serializable.

Comment: Can anyone please share logic or method to implement RSA on python dictionaries

Comment: You might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872643/6698642). Use `type()` to confirm that the objects are actually JSON serializable, and if not, then cast them to types that are.

Comment: Also, while your error message isn't `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`, they are usually not serializable. So can you try converting the `bytes` objects to a normal string and then try? You need to use `bytes.decode()`, with "utf-8" encoding I assume.

Comment: i converted the bytes keys into string. However after decryption I am not able to convert string keys into bytes again. I am sorry I am not a python guy much !

Comment: You can use the corresponding `encode()` method for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem isn't with the `bytes` as described below, you can narrow down on what causes the issue by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872643/6698642) and figuring out which of your variables are not serializable.

---

Your items in `secret_keys` are `bytes`, which are not JSON serializable. So you'll have to convert them to normal `str` objects. You can do so via the `decode` method as follows:

```
plainstr = bytestr.decode("utf-8") 
# The encoding passed need not be "utf-8", but it is quite common
```

Similarly, you can `encode` a `str` to `bytes` as follows:

```
encodedstr = plainstr.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks! got the expected output